# Is it feasible to put frequently changing data in cacheworker role in azure?

Tags: caching, azure, azure-worker-roles, trading

In trading application data changes in each second. We are putting data in a DataCache object in worker role

```
public class TradeData
  {
      public int LoginId;
      public double Price;
      public long Time;
      public int Profit;
      public string Quote;
      public double commission;
  }

putting data in a cache in infinite loop like
DataCache dc = new DataCache("Trade")
while(true)
{
  TradeData[] TradeInfo = GetDataFromAPI();
  foreach(var t in TradeInfo )
  {
     dc.put(t.LoginId.Tostring(),t)
  }

}
```

Is it feasible to put frequently changing data in cacheworker role in azure?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it depends but probably yes

I'm assuming that you're using cache as a data distribution mechanism - instead of going to storage your consumers are going to cache to find latest values.  This saves you on performance as well as cost of table storage transactions

Writes and reads from cache are generally going to be very fast.  If you do not enable redundancy in your dedicate cache, your cached data will only be stored in one place - thus not putting the burden onto cache nodes to duplicate the frequently changing data.

Do be aware that if you care more about data accuracy then data performance, you'll likely want to consider going to durable central storage instead of cache.

If you are going to use cache, I would implement dedicated cache and not collocated cache and use less of more powerful servers rather than more of less powerful servers.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Do performance tests before finalising an approach. Azure cache is fast, but not *that* fast. It is faster than getting data out of a contended database, but not significantly faster than table/blob storage. If you are running on a lot of nodes, the likelihood of the data being on *this* machine is low, so most reads will have to fetch data from another node — this will need a network read, and processing on a machine that might be a bit busy doing something else (Azure cache doesn't replicate, it distributes).

Yes, it may be feasible, but if you are looking for performance gains, Azure cache may not be the most performant. Do some realistic tests first, and compare different options. You may be surprised that table/blob storage outperforms cache.

Comment: If we put 1000 records in dedicated cache role, it takes around 8-10 seconds, but table takes much more time than cache worker role. Is there any way good approach.

Comment: I am using a small VM size for cache worker role and worker role.